# Google Maps API Infowindow with picture (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im trying to show a picture inside custom Infowindow with piccaso but it doesn't seem to work.
Evey marker Tag is 0 at start. I get the url srting with a map of markers id's and their unique url as a value.
My code:

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window,null);

            ImageView picture = v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            int flag = (Integer) marker.getTag();


            String url = allMarkersMap.get(marker.getId());
            if (url.equals("null")){}else {
                if (flag==0){marker.setTag(1);
                    Picasso.with(MapActivity.this).load(url).into(picture, new InfoWindowRefresher(marker);}
                else{Picasso.with(MapActivity.this).load(url).into(picture);}
            }
            // String picURL = allMarkersMap.get(marker);
            TextView title =  v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setText(marker.getTitle());


            return v;
        }
    });
```

InfoWindowRefresher:

```
 public class InfoWindowRefresher implements Callback {
    Marker marker=null;



    InfoWindowRefresher(Marker marker) {
        this.marker=marker;

    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        //Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error loading thumbnail!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        if (marker != null && marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
            marker.hideInfoWindow();


            marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and i solved it like this:

- I implement my logic inside `getInfoWindow` method and not `getInfoContents`

- inside `getInfoWindow`, i load the image but i add the refresher callback **only if** the `marker.isInfoWindowShown()`

- finally in the success callback:

```
 if (marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            marker.hideInfoWindow();
            marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
```

Comment: this line url.equals("null"); is not so safe

Comment: the url's were too big or something, its working if you put resize() in the load line, thank you for your help!